# How do you hide the waterfall scope in an Icom IC-705 and display just the meters?

Tags: panadapter-and-waterfall, icom-ic-705

I've seen the display in that mode but I'm failing to reproduce it. Any ideas how to hide the waterfall scope entirely (not just make it smaller)?

Answer (score 1):

Long press the one meter you see, that's always visible on the left above the waterfall.

Comment: Long pressing the meter makes the waterfall scope smaller and shows some meters below them, but doesn't completely hide the waterfall and show only meters.

Comment: Oh... but once it's in that mode, pressing M.SCOPE, hides the scope. This is somewhat confusing.

Comment: Yeah, I only have a 7300, and while I don't have it in front of me, I believe pressing "Exit" removes the waterfall. And once the waterfall is gone, the meters (when long pressing) should take up the rest of the space.